# Append inner 0 & 1st index to all elements in 2nd index two-dimensional List of Lists - python

Tags: python, list, 2d

Hello new to python here... wondering what the best way is to solve a problem like this.

I have a 2d array that look something like this:

```
a = [['October 17', 'Manhattan', '10024, 10025, 10026'], 
     ['October 17', 'Queen', '11360, 11362, 11365, 11368']]
```

Would like to iterate over this to create a new list or data frame that looks like the following:

```
10024, October 17, Manhattan
10025, October 17, Manhattan
10026, October 17, Manhattan
11360, October 17, Queens
11362, October 17, Queens
11365, October 17, Queens
11368, October 17, Queens
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the data really like this ? Or is it list of list of 3 items (comma missing) ?

Comment: My apologies here is the exact data `a = [['October 17', 'Manhattan', '10024, 10025, 10026'], ['October 17', 'Queen', '11360, 11362, 11365, 11368']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to iterate over the values, and for each iterate over the several indices you have

```
values = [['October 17', 'Manhattan', '10024, 10025, 10026'],
          ['October 17', 'Queens', '11360, 11362, 11365, 11368']]

result = [[int(idx), row[0], row[1]]
          for row in values
          for idx in row[2].split(',')]
df = DataFrame(result, columns=['idx', 'date', 'place'])
```

To obtain

```
[[10024, 'October 17', 'Manhattan'], [10025, 'October 17', 'Manhattan'], 
 [10026, 'October 17', 'Manhattan'], [11360, 'October 17', 'Queens'], 
 [11362, 'October 17', 'Queens'], [11365, 'October 17', 'Queens'], 
 [11368, 'October 17', 'Queens']]


     idx        date      place
0  10024  October 17  Manhattan
1  10025  October 17  Manhattan
2  10026  October 17  Manhattan
3  11360  October 17     Queens
4  11362  October 17     Queens
5  11365  October 17     Queens
6  11368  October 17     Queens
```

Answer (score 0):

Azro's answer is great, but here's a way to solve this problem that is more explicit (if you're truly new to Python, this approach might be more clear so you can understand what is happening — it doesn't rely on nested list comprehension.)

```
a = [['October 17', 'Manhattan', '10024, 10025, 10026'], 
['October 17', 'Queen', '11360, 11362, 11365, 11368']]

# initialize an empty list to put our reformatted data into
final_result = []

for inner_list in a:
    # get the first two items
    first_item = inner_list[0]
    second_item = inner_list[1]

    # split the third list item, and remove trailing and leading whitespace
    remaining_data = [x.strip() for x in inner_list[2].split(',')]

    # iterate over the remaining data
    for item in remaining_data:
        # first, create a new sublist containing our first two items
        new_entry = [item, first_item, second_item]

        # add our new_entry into the final result list
        final_result.append(new_entry)

print(final_result)
```